# Charts within a Userform none of the methods has worked

Tags: excel, vba, charts, combobox, userform

I have used 
Stephen Bullen's PastePicture Function but due to .dll
As well as other trends.

Goal: Userform1 has two Images and two combobox. 
The user clicks on one of 4 options ( chtMains1,chtMains2,chtMains3,chtMains4, )
and does that again for the other combobox. This in turn displays the charts.

Answer (score 0):

PastePicture can be interesting, especially with all the Win7 and 32/64-bit intricacies of the Windows API. You didn't say what "didn't work" about this function.

John Walkenbach uses a simpler approach that exports the chart as a .gif, then loads the .gif into an image control on the UserForm. See [Displaying A Chart In A Userform](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/displaying_a_chart_in_a_userform/)./